# Using custom .jar's in your java project

Tags: java

I'm importing from two jar's twitter4j-2.0.10.jar and mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar, I'm running the code on a server but it's not letting me. I get a..

```
 Streamer.java:9: package twitter4j does not exist
 import twitter4j.StatusDeletionNotice;
             ^
```

error when compiling. I know this has something to do with getting java to recognise my custom jar's but I don't know how to get java to "see" them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [set the classpath](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) for Javac.

One possible example (Windows, with your jar files in a folder called "lib"):

```
javac -classpath lib/twitter4j-2.0.10.jar;lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar MyClass.java
```

That's a very precise example though, your environment could differ considerably.

Comment: Why doesn't the following work?

javac -classpath twitter4j-2.1.2.jar;mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar; *.java

All jar's and source files are in the same directory. (which I run this command in)

Comment: That last semi-colon could be problematic.  The semi-colon is a path separator, but you don't have any path to separate after the last one.  What is the error message now?